# Webpacker with Rails compiles scss partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, sass, webpacker

I have created a sample app at https://github.com/joostvanrijn/webpacker to be complete, but here's my issue:

```
# app/javascript/packs/stylesheets.scss

@import 'variables';
@import 'foo';

# app/javascript/packs/_variables.scss

$bar: #fff;

# app/javascript/packs/_foo.scss

body {
  color: $bar;
}
```

Now when I run `/bin/webpack-dev-server` I get

```
Undefined variable: "$bar".
```

And more importantly

```
[84] ./app/javascript/packs/_foo.scss 988 bytes {2} [built] [failed] [1 error]
```

It seems as if Rails/webpacker compiles all files instead of just `stylesheets.scss`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to find the answer eventually.

From the Webpacker readme:

```
The configuration for what Webpack is supposed to compile by default 
rests on the convention that every file in app/javascript/packs/*
(default) or whatever path you set for source_entry_path in the 
webpacker.yml configuration is turned into their own output files (or 
entry points, as Webpack calls it).
```

So by moving the sass partials to another folder now only the stylesheets.scss gets compiled.